# Web Dev - Where to store state of a shopping-cart-like object?

Tags: cookies, state

You're building a web application. You need to store the state for a *shopping cart like* object during a user's session.

Some notes:

- This is not exactly a shopping cart, but more like an itinerary that the user is building... but we'll use the word cart for now b/c ppl relate to it.
- You do not care about "abandoned" carts
- Once a cart is completed we will persist it to some server-side data store for later retrieval.

**Where** do you store that stateful object? And **how**?

- server (session, db, etc?)
- client (cookie key-vals, cookie JSON object, hidden form-field, etc?)
- other...

**Update**: It was suggested that I list the platform we're targeting - tho I'm not sure its totally necessary... but lets say the front-end is built w/ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 27):

It's been my experience with the Commerce Starter Kit and MVC Storefront (and other sites I've built) that no matter what you think now, information about user interactions with your "products" is paramount to the business guys. There's so many metrics to capture - it's nuts.

I'll save you all the stuff I've been through - what's by far been the most successful for me is just creating an Order object with "NotCheckedOut" status and then adding items to it and the user adds items. This lets users have more than one cart and allows you to mine the tar out of the Orders table. It also is quite easy to transact the order - just change the status.

Persisting "as they go" also allows the user to come back and finish the cart off if they can't, for some reason. Forgiveness is massive with eCommerce.

Cookies suck, session sucks, Profile is attached to the notion of a user and it hits the DB so you might as well use the DB.

You might *think* you don't want to do this - but you need to *trust* me and know that you WILL indeed need to feed the stats wonks some data later. I promise you.

Answer (score 3):

I have considered what you are suggesting but have not had a client project yet to try it. The closest actually is a shopping list that you can find here...

http://www.scottcommonsense.com/toolbox.aspx

Click on Grocery Checklist to open the window. It does use ASPX, but only to manage the JS references placed on the page. The rest is done via AJAX using web services.

Previously I built an ASP.NET 2.0 site for a commerce site which used anon/auth cookies automatically. Each provides you with a GUID value which you can use to identify a user which is then associated with data in your database. I wanted the auth cookies so a user could move to different computers; work, home, etc. I avoided using the Profile fields to hold onto a complex ShoppingBasket object which was popular during the time in all the ASP.NET 2.0 books. I did not want to deal with "magic" serialization issues as the data structure changed over time. I prefer to manage db schema changes with update/alter scripts synced with software changes.

With the anon/auth cookies identifying the user on the client you can use the ASP.NET AJAX client-side to call the authentication web services using the JS proxies that are provided for you as a part of ASP.NET. You need to implement the Membership API to at least authenticate the user. The rest of the provider implementation can throw a NotImplementedException safely. You can then use your own custom ASMX web services via AJAX (see ScriptReference attribute) and update the pages with server-side data. You can completely do away with ASPX pages and just use static HTML/CSS/JS if you like.

The one big caveat is memory leaks in JS. Staying on the same page a long time increases your potential issue with memory leaks. It is a risk you can minimize by testing for long sessions and using tools like Firebug and others to look for memory leaks. Use the JS Lint tool as well as it will help identify major problems as you go.

Comment: I like this approach, except I'll likely use MVC and RESTful AJAX calls (returning JSON or markup) so I won't need to worry about the ASMX nor ASPX cruft.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be inclined to store it as a session object.  This is because you're not concerned with abandoned carts, and can therefore remove the overhead of storing it in the database as it's not necessary (not to mention that you'd also need some kind of cleanup routine to remove abandoned carts from the database).

However, if you'd like users to be able to persist their carts, then the database option is better.  This way, a user who is logged in will have their cart saved across sessions (so when they come back to the site and login, their cart will be restored).

You could also use a combination of the two.  Users who come to the site use the session-based cart by default.  When they log in, all items are moved from the session-based cart to a database-based cart, and any subsequent cart activity is applied directly to the database.

Comment: I think this is a valid suggestion - except I'd probably use client-side cookie w/JSON data rather than session...

Comment: What about the size limits of cookies? What about cookie tampering? It might be okay for a list, but for a cart it seems really crude? What happens if you change the data schema?

Answer (score 1):

In the DB tied to whatever you're using for sessions (db/memcache sessions, signed cookies) or to an authenticated user.

Comment: There may not even be a db (at least not a relational one)... :)

Comment: Store it in your "server-side" data store :). Why have 2 different data stores? Storing server side adds more flexibility and security.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the platform I can't give a direct answer. However, since you don't care about abandoned carts, then I would differ from my colleagues here and suggest storing it on the client. Why store it in the database if you don't care if it's abandoned? 
Then again, it does depend on the size of the object you're storing -- cookies have their limits after all. 
 
Edit: Ahh, asp.net MVC? Why not use the profile system? You can enable an anonymous profile if you don't want to bother making them log in

Answer (score 1):

Do you envision folks needing to be able to start on one machine (e.g. their work PC) but continue/finsih from a different machine (e.g. home PC)?  If so, the answer is obvious.

Comment: That is not a scenario we plan to support for anonymous users - tho we may support it for authenticated users.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about abandoned carts and have things in place for someone messing with the data on the client side... I think a cookie would be good -- especially if it's just a cookie of JSON data.

Comment: Cookies are limited to 4K. That may not be enough data, depending on the size of the shopping cart.

Comment: Yea, I agree it really depends on the requirements of the app as to whether or not this would be the best route.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an (encrypted) cookie on the client which holds the ID of the users basket.  Unless it's a really busy site then abandoned baskets won't fill up the database by *too* much, and you can run a regular admin task to clear the abandoned orders down if you care that much.  Also doing it this way the user will keep their order if they close their browser and go away, a basket in the session would be cleared at this point..

Finally this means that you don't have to worry about writing code to deal with de/serialising the data from a client-side cookie, while later worrying about actually putting that data into the database when it gets converted into an order (too many points of failure for my liking)..

Answer (score 1):

I'd say store the state somewhere on the server and correlate it to the user's session. While a cookie could ostensibly be an equal place to store things, if you consider security and data size, keeping as much data on the server as possible becomes a good thing.

For example, in a public terminal setting, would it be OK for someone to look at the contents of the cookie and see the list? If so, cookie's fine; if not, you'll just want an ID that links the user to the data. Doing that would also allow you to ensure the user is authenticated to the site in order to get to that data rather than storing everything on the machine - they'd need some form of credentials *as well as* the session identifier.

From a size perspective, sure, you're not going to be too concerned about a 4K cookie or something for a browser/broadband user, but if one of your targets is to allow a mobile phone or BlackBerry (not on 3G) to connect and have a snappy experience (and not get billed for the data), minimizing the amount of data getting passed to the client will be key.

The server storage also gives you some flexibility mentioned in some of the other answers - the user can save their cart on one machine and resume working with it on another; you can tie the cart to some form of credentials (rather than a transient session) and persist the cart long after the user has cleared their cookies; you get a little more in the way of fault tolerance - if the user's browser crashes, the site still has the data safe and sound.

If fault tolerance is important, you'll need some sort of persistent store like a database. If not, in application memory is probably fine, but you'll lose data if the app restarts. If you're in a farm environment, the store has to be centrally accessible, so you're again looking at a database.

Whether you choose to key by transient session or by credentials is going to depend on whether the users can save their data and come back later to get it. Transient session will eventually get cleaned up as "abandoned," and maybe that's OK. Tying to a user profile will let the user keep their data and explicitly abandon it. Either way, I'd make use of some sort of backing store like a database for fault tolerance and central accessibility. (Or maybe I'm overengineering the solution?)

Answer (score 0):

If you care about supporting users without Javascript enabled, then the server side sessions will let you use URL rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

If a relatively short time-out (around 2 hours, depending on your server config) is OK for the cart, then I'd say the server-side session. It's faster and more efficient than accessing the DB.

If you need a longer persistence (say some users like to leave and come back the next day), then store it in a cookie that is tamper-evident (use encryption or hashes).